# Implications from unprovable statements

Tags: logic

Consider that $p$ is an unprovable statement in a certain set of axioms.

Now consider that there exists a statement $q$ such that, through the same axioms, $$(p \implies q) \land (\lnot p \implies q)$$

Can we assume that the statement $q$ is true, even though we do not though whether $p$ is true or false? Or does $p$ being unprovable imply a certain  $3$-valued boolean that breaks the implication?

Comment: With no parentheses, "and" has higher priority than "implies". So should your displayed statement be $(p \implies q) \land (\lnot p \implies q)$?

Comment: @coffeemath Oops, yes it should, I've corrected it

Comment: If your axiom system allows use of modus ponens, then since $[(p \implies q) \land (\lnot p \implies q)] \implies q$ is a tautology, $q$ itself is provable regardless of what $p$ might be, provable or not.

Comment: Is there any axiom system that wouldn't allow modus ponens? From what I've read it seems to be a property of propositional logic, which I believe is at the basis of any axiom construction

Comment: I agree about modus ponens being there in some way in most axiom systems. It may not be given as one of the axioms of the system, but if the system is strong enough to derive the usual theorems of propositional logic, then something like modus ponens must reside in the "rules of deduction" part. I mean the axioms are listed, and then some way to deduce results is somehow given also. Without any form of modus ponens it would be hard to "get off the ground." [However there may be such a system... beyond my knowledge.]

Comment: If proposition $A$ is false, then the implication $\neg A \implies B$ is vacuously true, regardless of the truth value of $B$. Does that mean that $B$ is "unprovable" in this case?

Comment: (Correction) If proposition $A$ is false, then the implication $A\implies B$ is vacuously true, regardless of the truth value of B. Does that mean that B is "unprovable" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposition:

$$(P ⇒ Q) ∧ (¬P ⇒ Q)$$

is (typically) equivalent to:

$$(P ∨ ¬P) ⇒ Q$$

Therefore, whether or not we can deduce $Q$ (from the above), absent a way to deduce either $P$ or $¬P$ depends on excluded middle for $P$.

So, according to classical logic, $Q$ is deducible, and must be true. But e.g. in constructive logic this is no longer necessarily the case. Whether or not a 3-valued logic is also a counterexample probably depends on exactly the flavor of 3-valued logic you're using (and it's conceivable that it affects the original equivalence as well; I'm not an expert in 3-valued logic).